# Who called Paul: Jesus or the Holy Spirit?

Tags: jesus, contradiction, acts, paul, pneumatology

> 15 But **the Lord said to him**, “Go, **for he is a chosen instrument of mine** to carry **my name** before the Gentiles and kings and the children of Israel. 16 **For I will show him** how much he must suffer **for the sake of my name**.” [Acts 9:15-16 ESV]

vs.

> 2 While they were **worshiping the Lord** and fasting, **the Holy Spirit said**, “**Set apart for me** Barnabas and Saul for the work to which **I have called them**.” [Acts 13:2 ESV]

Who called Paul: Jesus or the Holy Spirit?

Comment: The Lord, the spirit 2 Cor 3:18

Comment: Jesus called Saul of Tarsus on the Damascus Road. The Spirit separated Saul from among the congregation in Antioch.

Comment: Non-trinitarians would say that Jesus used his holy spirit as the medium of communication. Simple, obvious, non-confusing, no problem.  Not personifying holy spirit makes so many issues cease to exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two incidents quoted by the OP are discussing quite different occasions:

- **Acts 9:15** is describing the call to ministry and apostleship of Paul by Jesus Christ Himself.
- **Acts 13:2** is describing the calling by the Holy Spirit of Paul and Barnabas for a particular mission - the first missionary tour in this case - just one of many such callings that Paul would receive.  Another such is recorded in Acts 16:6.

Thus, Paul was called to his life-long work at conversion by Jesus Christ personally.  The Holy Spirit called and directed Paul at a variety of times throughout the rest of his life to do or not to do various things within that general calling to apostleship.